# Write a single generics method to cover multiple methods for String to Enum value conversion

Tags: java, generics, enums

I created two Java enums,

```
public enum TypeEnum {
    TYPE_A, TYPE_B
}
```

and

```
public enum FormatEnum{
    FORMAT_X, FORMAT_Y
}
```

Next, I wrote two functions to convert an incoming String to an enum value:

```
private TypeEnum convertType(String test) {
    return TypeEnum.valueOf(test);
}
private FormatEnum convertFormat(String test) {
    return FormatEnum.valueOf(test);
}
```

Next, I wanted to unify these two conversion methods under a single method with generics. I tried this in two ways:

```
private <T extends Enum> Enum convertToEnumValue(T localEnum, String value) {
    return T.valueOf(localEnum.getClass(), value);
}
```

and

```
private static <T extends Enum> T convertToEnumValue(Class<T> enumType, String value) {
    return (T) T.valueOf(enumType, value);
}
```

I couldn't write a call to these methods that would compile.

Is there a way to correct them to make them work?

Comment: You could perhaps use reflection with a `Class<T>`, but what you have right now should be good enough

Comment: Hey @Rokas. Both of your methods require the caller to pass in whatever specific type of _`Enum`_ they want to convert. Right? If that's the case, then what use case do you have in mind where consumers of these methods would need to convert a string to a type they already have right there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to declare your own method, as JDK `java.lang.Enum` already declares one:

```
FormatEnum y =Enum.valueOf(FormatEnum.class, "FORMAT_Y");

TypeEnum a = Enum.valueOf(TypeEnum.class, "TYPE_A");
```

This works because Enum is the base class of all enum types and so when you call `TypeEnum.valueOf(s);` you are calling `Enum.valueOf(s)`

Answer (score 1):

> *…Is there a way to correct them to make them work?…*

I got your examples to work with these very small corrections…:

```
class DeduperAnswer {

    private <T extends Enum> T convertToEnumValue(T localEnum, String value) {
        return ( T ) T.valueOf(localEnum.getClass(), value);
    }

    private static <T extends Enum> T convertToEnumValue(Class<T> enumType, String value) {
        return ( T ) T.valueOf(enumType, value);
    }        

    static public void main(String ...args){

        DeduperAnswer da = new DeduperAnswer();

        TypeEnum typB = da.convertToEnumValue(TypeEnum.TYPE_B, "TYPE_B");

        FormatEnum fmtX = convertToEnumValue(FormatEnum.FORMAT_X.getClass(), "FORMAT_X");
    }
}
```

Of course, there's more than one way to skin a cat — *as the saying goes*. But seeing as your solution works for you, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for the following method:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E toMember(Class<E> clazz, String name) {
    //TODO input validations;
    for (E member : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (member.name().equals(name)) {
            return member;
        }
    }
    return null; //Or throw element not found exception
}

//More elegant form of the previous one
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E toMember(Class<E> clazz, String name, E defaultMember) {
    //TODO input validations;
    for (E member : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (member.name().equals(name)) {
            return member;
        }
    }
    return defaultMember;
}
```

Note the generic **E extends Enum<E>**

Comment: Although this method is truly generic is not as efficient as it could be. Since you already know your enum type I would recommend a name to member map inside the enum class. Therefore each time you want to retrieve a member by name you would only need to perform a nameToMember.get(name). This is far faster than the previously presented iteration approach.

Comment: Wouldn't [`Enum.valueOf(clazz, name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) be easier? (Except that you have to deal with the exception in the not-found case)